# Centralized Using keyword in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, header, using

Is there a way to make a single "header" type file in C#?

In C++ you had something like "Mainheader.h" that had all of your includes in it.

Is there a way to do something similar for C# where you had a single file with all of your "using" keywords?

Right now I have a bunch of using such as:

`using System; 

using System.Collections.Generic; 

using System.Linq;

using System.Web;

using System.Web.UI;

using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Net.Mail;`

Is there a way to put them all into a single header file?

Comment: No. Each file has to have its own using statements, one per line. If you want functionality like C++, why not just use C++? ;)

Comment: that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: And, well, usings are not includes, they only make namespaces visible to your code.

Comment: You don't need to have a single using statement provided you add the reference to the Visual Studio project and give the full namespace for everything.  What you want makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. The "mainheader.h" approach worked for C++ because headers are literally textual copy-and-pastes that compilers executed before actually compiling, hence the term "pre-processor directive".

What you may find useful is to create a template that contains some of your most commonly-used directives. Here's a link on how to do it in Visual Studio 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx.  You can do it in MonoDevelop as well, but it's a little trickier and involves editing XML directly. Hope this suffices as a workaround.

Answer (score 7):

No. Using directives only apply to the current source file.

Personally I wouldn't *want* to do this anyway - the `using` directives typically give me insight as to the sort of code I'll see in the class, and can indicate a code smell if there are too many disparate ones. (I try to remember to perform "Organize and Sort Usings" before checking in, too.)

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible.  The C# compiler doesn't support the notion centralizing `using` statements in a single file.