# c# where to place "using" for every page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have a

```
using MyProject.language;
```

literary needs to place on every single page.

My question is, is there a place that I can place the "using" just once, for every page of the project.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "page," is this an ASP.NET project? This inclusion IS possible in ASP.NET projects inside your web.config file, but not on Forms applications.

Comment: No, you have to use that on every file or part of the project/solution where you need to use classes/enums contained in `MyProject.language`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789239/does-c-sharp-support-project-wide-default-namespace-imports-like-vb-net

Comment: @lthibodeaux, yes it's ASP.net project, I found web.config has system.web -> pages -> namespaces -> "<add namespace="MyProject.language" />" . I tired, not working. Any idea

Comment: Please be aware that this only includes the namespace for page  directives (inside <% %> tags). It will not make the namespace available to code-behind for that page. Is that where your namespace import is not working?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7955762/60761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned page, you can configure ASP.NET to reference the namespace everywhere. This only affect the views themselves and not the code behind

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="xVal.Html" />
    <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

If you use the Razor view engine of ASP.NET MVC, you can add a reference for all views like this

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

If you are in a plain C# project or in the code behind of a page, you should know that any class that is located in a namespace will automatically reference all object in any parent namespace. Assuming a namespace `Company.Software.Somethings.Data`, any classes in the `Data` namespace will automatically reference the classes in

- `Company.Software.Somethings`
- `Company.Software`
- `Company`

Comment: Beat me to it, this is such a great feature.

Answer (score 3):

Using statements have to be in the file where you are actually using the namespace. There is no such thing as a one-place-for-all-usings in C#, unlike C++. The only 'exception' to this are ASP / ASP-MVC files, which automatically add all the using statements defined in the web.config `namespaces` node. C# / .cs files do not make use of this facility however and still need every namespace manually defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that, as this works only for one file.